# How to test next parameter in controller using mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, api, mocha.js, chai

I've got a controller which I'm using the 'next' parameter, and I have no idea how to include it into the test. I've done request and response, everything is ok, but when I use the next, I've got the error asking for the 3rd argument. How to test 'next' in this case?

**error**

```
Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
car.controller.ts(20, 5): An argument for 'next' was not provided.
```

**controller test**

```
describe('Cars Controller Tests', () => {
  const carModel = new CarModel();
  const carService = new CarService(carModel);
  const carController = new CarController(carService);
  const req = {} as Request;
  const res = {} as Response;

  before(async () => {
    sinon.stub(carService, 'create').resolves(mock.carMockWithId);
    res.status = sinon.stub().returns(res);
    res.json = sinon.stub().returns(res);
  });

  after(()=>{
    sinon.restore();
  })

  it('1 - CREATE runs successfully', async () => {
    req.body = mock.carMock;
    await carController.create(req, res);
    expect((res.status as unknown as sinon.SinonStub).calledWith(201)).to.be.true;
    expect((res.json as sinon.SinonStub).calledWith(mock.carMockWithId)).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: I would recommend **not** unit testing controllers. You end up creating complicated mocks of things (Express req, res, next) you don't own and coupling tests to implementation details not behaviour. Controllers belong to the transport layer, integration test them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got from an article I found:

declare Next then test as usual:

```
const req = {} as Request;
const res = {} as Response;
const next = {} as NextFunction;
....
await carController.create(req, res, next);
```